# How to interpret "merged manifest" content in Android studio to fix the error 'Manifest merger failed with multiple errors' in Android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I changed my app from targetsdkversion 30 to 33 and minsdk to 21 from build.gradle file but i get the error "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" when i try to build apk. How do i make sense of my AndroidManifest.xml and "merged manifest" resulting content shown below to fix this issue?

This is the errors fro "merged manifest" tab content

```
Merge Errors Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#id.platinum.android.feature.splash.SplashActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. lovpos_f.app main manifest (this file), line 79 Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.receiver.FreshchatReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. lovpos_f.app main manifest (this file) Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.receiver.FreshchatNetworkChangeReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. lovpos_f.app main manifest (this file)  Merge Warnings Warning: Element uses-permission#android.permission.BLUETOOTH at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-68 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-68 lovpos_f.app main manifest (this file), line 11
```

This is excerpt from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="id.platinum.android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="true" />

    <application
            android:name="id.platinum.android.MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            tools:targetApi="n">



        <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
                android:value="true"/>
        <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <meta-data
                android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
                android:value="${crashlyticsEnabled}"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/ic_logo_white"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>

        <provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="id.platinum.android.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
                    tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>

        <service
                android:name="id.platinum.android.services.notification.FirebaseMessagingService"
                android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log says that you have to add exported attribute to your  `<activity#id.platinum.android.feature.splash.SplashActivity>`

This may be your SplashActivity, this activity's code was missing in code you have posted. check whether you have this added this activity in your manifest, if yes add exported attribute.